# NetworkManager writing to resolv.conf every reboot, breaking dnsmasq?

Tags: networking, 18.04, network-manager, dns, dnsmasq

I am on *Ubuntu 18.04* using the `netplan` configuration which renders using `NetworkManager`:

```
# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
```

Every time I restart, the following output is automatically generated and written to `/etc/resolv.conf`, breaking my `dnsmasq` configuration in that I can no longer resolve domains on the internet:

```
# Generated by NetworkManager
nameserver 127.0.0.53
```

I can fix this manually by simply commenting out the nameserver line in /etc/resolv.conf. Before I write a script to perform this commenting out every reboot, I should understand what's going on.

This is my simple `/etc/dnsmasq.conf`:

```
port=53
domain-needed
bogus-priv
strict-order

server=/mydomain.net/10.0.0.2
server=/#/8.8.8.8

listen-address=127.0.0.1

bind-interfaces
```

1) Why is this being written by `NetworkManager` every reboot?

2) Why is it breaking `dnsmasq` anyway because the strict-order server settings should forward all other requests to google's DNS server? When `dnsmasq` is running, does the system look in resolv.conf first or after dnsmasq.conf?

Comment: The problem is due to a couple of problems. Understand that DNS in 18.xx is kinda screwball. Edit your question with the output from `ls -al /etc/resolv.conf` and `ps auxc | grep dns` and `ps auxc | grep resolv` and `cat /run/resolvconf/resolv.conf` and `cat /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf`. Are you using dnsmasq for DNS, or DHCP? Did you install it, or did it come over from an upgrade?

Comment: I totally don't understand what's going on - why does `dnsmasq` only work when the contents of `/etc/resolv.conf` are empty if `systemd-resolvd` is disabled?

Comment: If you respond to my earlier comment, I'll have some info to go on. Also show me `cat /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`.

Answer (score 9):

Same problem with dnsmasq:

1. Edit `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`and after `[Main]` add ***or change*** to `dns=none`. Save the file.
2. Execute `systemctl restart NetworkManager.service` (please note uppercase and lowercase).
3. Edit `/etc/resolv.conf` with your values. Save the file.

**Optional testing**: reboot and confirm.

Hope be useful, thanks for your attention.

Comment: OMG thatnks a ton!  NetworkManager and dnsmasq have been a thorn in my side for the last week